# Detect if user did not touch object

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, touch

I'm developing an iOS app for iPad. I use I code to detect when does the user touch an object, but now I'd like to use the same code to detect when the user does not touch the object. This is the code:

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(ribbon.frame, location) || CGRectContainsPoint(inferior.frame, location) || CGRectContainsPoint(superior.frame, location) & (pujat==YES)){
    pujat=NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        superior.frame = CGRectMake(0, 710, 1024,500);
        ribbon.frame = CGRectMake(480, 685, 70,70);
        inferior.frame = CGRectMake(0, 750, 1024,500);}];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:inferior];

}
}
```

So how can I detect when the user touches the screen but not a certain object?

Answer (score 3):

Actually CGRectContainsPoint will return false if the touch point is not on the certain object. Say you want to check if the touch point is in ribbon or not. Only a "!" will be enough.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(ribbon.frame, location) || CGRectContainsPoint(inferior.frame,     location) || CGRectContainsPoint(superior.frame, location) & (pujat==YES)){

        if(!CGRectContainsPoints(ribbon.frame,location))
            NSLog("Touch point is not on ribbon");

        pujat=NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        superior.frame = CGRectMake(0, 710, 1024,500);
        ribbon.frame = CGRectMake(480, 685, 70,70);
        inferior.frame = CGRectMake(0, 750, 1024,500);}];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:inferior];
    }
}
```